# "Undefined variable from import: SLOT" in PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, slot

I was trying the following PyQt5 code from the answers in
[Singleshot: SLOT with arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7489262/683218):

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore
QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(1, self, QtCore.SLOT(recall(arg1)), arg1)
```

But I get an error about the `QtCore.SLOT` part that says:

> Undefined variable from import: SLOT

I'm new to PyQt5, and I am wondering:

*Is this error due to version differences between PyQt 4 and 5?*

*What's the right way of writing it in PyQt5?*

Comment: That method no longer exists in PyQt5, it uses a lambda function as the other answer shows: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7497574/6622587

Comment: @eyllanesc Thanks! if you make your comment an answer, I'll accept it.